# Bean validation value

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to experiments with bean validation. The following code fragment:

```
    <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{hello.sur}"/>
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" 
                     action="response">
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:commandButton id="reset" value="Reset" type="reset">
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{hello.sur}"/>
</h:form>
```

Where `private String sur` property in `Hello` annotated with `@DecimalMin("5.00")` 
When i passing to `id1` value greater then `5` and `id2` is empty i have no error. Why? But if both `id1` and `id2` are epmty i have error.

Comment: FIrst, why do you have two separated forms? Second, in your command button you don't have any actions, it should be evaluate to an action from the `hello` like `action=#{hello.someMethodToBind}`. And what is the error ?

Comment: @Jorge Campos _First, why do you have two separated forms?_ For experiments only. _in your command button you don't have any actions_ `<h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="response">` I have no error message such as _must be greater than or equal to 5.00_

Comment: Thats because you are not processing any request. JSF doesnt work like a normal submit, you have to have some method to process your request so that in the JSF phases the error cames up before the rendering phase, if I'm not mistake it would be in validation phase

Comment: @Jorge Campos I dont understand you. Why contraints from bean validation cannot applied to `inputText` from different `form`?

Comment: It can, but for your example does not make sense. I just ask because I'm thinking the probably right way. But if it isn't then you need to call some action on both forms.

Comment: What's this error when leaving the two inputs empty ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bean validation and 2 form in facelet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173722/bean-validation-and-2-form-in-facelet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there're some imbalances in your question/code: First, the property `sure` should have numeric type, not a string, second, you're providing a value that is greater than 5, which means the validation, if performed, will not be triggred (no error message).
Also, while this is an experiment, you can omit the `<commandButton />`'s and should make your managed-bean `@ViewScoped` in order to perform tests as long as you're in the same page, that's why, `<f:ajax>` tags are used, in order to refresh some fragements (components) in the view at runtime without the need to refresh all the page (send request), this is useful for conversion/validation. For better practice, make these changes and provide a value that's less than 5 :

```
<h:form> 
       <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{hello.sur}">
           <f:ajax event="blur" render="id1Message"/>
       </h:inputText>
       <h:message for="id1" id="id1Message"/>

       <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{hello.anotherProperty}">
           <f:ajax event="blur" render="id2Message"/>
       </h:inputText>
       <h:message for="id2" id="id2Message"/>    
</h:form>
```