# Bean validation and 2 form in facelet

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, bean-validation

I have 2 forms in facelet, `1.xhtml`

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{mBean.pr}"/>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="response"/>
</h:form>
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="myCB" action="response"/>
    <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{mBean.pr}"/>
</h:form>
```

`pr` field annotated by `@DecimalMin("5.00")`. In this case its sufficient that `id1` or `id2` contains value greater or equal to 5.00. But consider the following facelet `2.xhtml`

```
 <h:form>
        <h:inputText id="id1" value="#{hello.sur}"/>
        <h:inputText id="id2" value="#{hello.sur}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="response">
        </h:commandButton>
 </h:form>
```

In this, both `id1` and `id2` must contain value greater then `5.00`.

i dont understand why it's occurring?

Comment: I am not sure what you meant. But from what I understood, in the first case, as you are using two forms, when you submit a particular form validation check of value in that particular form is done. In the second case, as both values are in the same form both fields are validated while submitting. If this is not what you meant, please clarify.

Comment: It seems that you're somehow expecting that all inputs of a **different** form are also submitted, processed, converted, validated and updated when you submit a certain form, is this true? Why exactly? HTML namely doesn't work that way!

Comment: @BalusC exactly! I'm understand you, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms doesn't work that way. When you submit a certain form, only the inputs **inside** the form are sent, processed, converted, validated and updated in the model. Forms are submitted on a per-form basis, not on a per-page basis or so. A page can have multiple forms with completely different responsibilities, e.g. a login form and a contact form. When you submit the login form, it wouldn't make sense to process the inputs of the contact form and show validation errors on them.

Actually, you should also have a separate request/view scoped backing bean per form. This is not a technical requirement, but just a "good design" requirement.